# Autoware Auto - Record/Replay a Trajectory in LGSVL

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I was trying to use "Record/Replay a Trajectory in LGSVL" from [here](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/recordreplay-planner-howto.html).

And noticed that the below command does not seem to be working.

```
ros2 action send_goal /planning/recordtrajectory autoware_auto_msgs/action/RecordTrajectory "{record_path: "/tmp/path"}" --feedback
```

`The passed action type is invalid`

To find the right action, I searched in `ros2 interface list` and updated the command as below.

```
ros2 action send_goal /planning/recordtrajectory recordreplay_planner_actions/action/RecordTrajectory "{record_path: "/tmp/path"}" --feedback
```

The updated command seems to be working to record the path.

Similarly for "Reply" I used the below command.

```
ros2 action send_goal /planning/replaytrajectory recordreplay_planner_actions/action/ReplayTrajectory "{replay_path: "/tmp/path"}" --feedback
```

Could anybody please check and confirm on the same.

I have tried updating the `ade` by following the below steps. The version is `4.2.0`.

```
kishor@kishor:~/adehome/AutowareAuto$ ade stop
kishor@kishor:~/adehome/AutowareAuto$ 
kishor@kishor:~/adehome/AutowareAuto$ ade start --update
1.0.0: Pulling from autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/amd64/ade-foxy
Digest: sha256:eac0688314b5c8e846acc769fa18c54de438234a6a863d5d1764433a4c29ac2e
Status: Image is up to date for registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/amd64/ade-foxy:1.0.0
registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/amd64/ade-foxy:1.0.0
1.0.0: Pulling from autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/amd64/binary-foxy
Digest: sha256:432f5513b0c5608a4d44931234beee7422532dac6595ff98a1911cd8a58aaed3
Status: Image is up to date for registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/amd64/binary-foxy:1.0.0
registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/amd64/binary-foxy:1.0.0
Starting ade with the following images:
ade-foxy    | 1.0.0 | 1.0.0 | registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/amd64/ade-foxy:1.0.0   
binary-foxy | 1.0.0 | 1.0.0 | registry.gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autowareauto/amd64/binary-foxy:1.0.0
ade_registry.gitlab.com_autowarefoundation_autoware.auto_autowareauto_amd64_binary-foxy_1.0.0
non-network local connections being added to access control list

Current default time zone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
Local time is now:      Fri Jun 25 11:08:47 IST 2021.
Universal Time is now:  Fri Jun 25 05:38:47 UTC 2021.

Adding user kishor to group video
Adding user kishor to group dialout
ADE startup completed.

ADE has been started, enter or run commands using: ade enter

kishor@kishor:~/adehome/AutowareAuto$ ade --version
4.2.0
kishor@kishor:~/adehome/AutowareAuto$
```

Is 4.2.0 the latest version?

And also I have captured the `ros2 interface list` for the msgs and actions available in the pre-built version. `Actions` given below:

```
Actions:
    autoware_auto_msgs/action/PlanTrajectory
    recordreplay_planner_actions/action/RecordTrajectory
    recordreplay_planner_actions/action/ReplayTrajectory
    tf2_msgs/action/LookupTransform
```

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380264/autoware-auto---record/replay-a-trajectory-in-lgsvl/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2021-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2021-06-23**:
Are you building Autoware from source or using the pre-built installation in `/opt/AutowareAuto` in Docker? Are you running `ade` or just building from source on a host machine? Which version of Autoware.Auto?

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-06-23**:
@Josh, I am using the Autoware pre-built installation. And I am running on `ade`.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2021-06-23**:
Which version? Have you updated `ade` recently with the --update flag?

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-06-24**:
ADE Version is 4.2.0. Yes, I have updated the ade recently. I am following this [link](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/lgsvl.html) to launch Autoware with LGSvl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try updating your `ade` containers again. We (somewhat) recently moved the actions for the Record/Replay Planner from the package `recordreplay_planner_actions` to `autoware_auto_msgs` but the latest installation in `/opt/AutowareAuto` of the `ade` containers should have this update applied.

Please also verify that you have no old instances of `ade` already running by first running `ade stop` and then `ade start --update --enter` from within your AutowareAuto folder.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-06-25**:
Thanks for the answer.
Is 4.2.0 the latest ade version? I have also updated my question with more details and steps followed.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2021-06-25**:
You didn't mention previously that you were using the 1.0.0 version. In this version, the action *was* under `recordreplay_planner_actions`. This is not a problem with the docs, but with *which* docs you are using. We are currently transitioning to ReadTheDocs to be able to host multiple versions of our docs (`master`, `release`, and tagged release versions). Here are the docs specific to the current latest release (1.0.0): https://autowareauto.readthedocs.io/en/release/.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-06-25**:
Sorry, I did not notice that.
Thanks for the clarification Josh. I will follow the right documents.